# Invariance of the basis for the definition of degree for finite-dimensional vector spaces

Tags: analysis, nonlinear-analysis

Let $(V, ||\cdot||)$ be vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ normed and finite-dimensional $n$, $\Omega \subset V$ open and bounded, $\varphi: \overline{ \Omega} \to V$ continuous and $b \not\in \varphi(\partial \Omega)$. Fixing the bases
$$\mathcal{B} = \{v_1, \ldots, v_n\} \ \ \mbox{e} \ \ \mathcal{C} = \{e_1, \ldots, e_n\}$$ of $V$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$, respectively, we can consider linear isomorphism $T: V \to \mathbb{R}^n$ satisfying
$$T(v_i) = e_i,$$
for all $i \in \{1, \ldots, n\}$. Under these conditions, we can take the commutative diagram

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
\overline{\Omega} @>{\varphi}>> V\\
@V{T}VV @VV{T}V\\
T(\overline{\Omega}) @>>{f}> \mathbb{R}^n
\end{CD}

that motivates us to define
$$d_V(\varphi, \Omega, b) := d_{\mathbb{R}^n}(f, T(\Omega), T(b))$$
to be the topological degree of $\varphi$ over the vector space $V$ in $\Omega$ at point $b$.

**Question:** How to show that such a definition is independent of the base of $V$? In other words, for any other base $\mathcal{B'} = \{w_1, \ldots, w_n\}$ of $V$, in which the application is defined $S: V \to \mathbb{R} ^n$ that satisfies
$$S(w_i) = e_i,$$
for all $i \in \{1, \ldots, n\}$, how to show that
$$d_{\mathbb{R}^n}(f, T(\Omega), T(b)) = d_{\mathbb{R}^n}(S \circ \varphi \circ S^{-1 }|_{S(\overline{\Omega})}, S(\Omega), S(b))?$$